# javascript variable scope binding using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs/javascript code for image Uploading but i got stuck in variable binding , can anyone help me out, here is my code.

```
var image_source;
$scope.uploadedFile = function(element) {
  reader.onload = function(event) {
  image_source = event.target.result;
  $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
    $scope.files = element.files;
  });
}
console.log(image_source,event.target.result, element.files[0],  "***not working here***");
```

I'm binding varibale named `image_source` within function but when i access this outside the function it always return undefined why ?

PS:- i can get this in the typescript using `phatarrow operator` but how to do in javascript i dont know

Comment: where you had declared image_source??

Comment: try declaring it outside of the scope

Comment: i have declared outside the function

Comment: File operation is Async operation. You are assigning  value to  `image_source` inside onload method.  It may be the reason for not working

Comment: its function-scoped, not sure why u r expecting it to be accessible outside. fat-arrow function gets the scope of the parent-block and hence it might work in es6. r u expecting block-scope in es5?? that wont work.

Comment: @Plankton yes exactly i am working with es5, and problem is related to blocked scoped,in some cases i need to access this outside from the fiunction

Comment: @Ved so what to do ?

Comment: why so many downvotes ? is it invalid question ?

Comment: @PardeepJain check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068610/read-a-file-synchronously-in-javascript

Comment: @Ved thank for the reference but this does't solve my problem i think, can you post your useful answer ? so that i am able to get value outside in the console

Comment: @PardeepJain I am confused here why do you want to access `image_source` value outside the method. As `image_source` is empty.

Answer (score -1):

If your `console.log` statement is called before `$scope.uploadedFile` which is most likely to be the case, the value will not be set, I suggest you try to call the function and put your console.log statement at the end of the function, inside the block.

That's not an angular issue but more like javascript, when you declare an anonymous function it's not called immediately

```
let mynumber = 1
let myfunction = () => { 
    mynumber = 2
}
console.log(mynumber) // 1
myfunction()
console.log(mynumber) // 2
```

Comment: yes i know but i have to console outside from the fuction in some case

Comment: I'm not sure it's useful, I assume that the chunk of file that you're showing here is your controller? 

You just can't put your console log statement before a function sets the value and then expect it to be set

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to acheive, if your console.log statement is only intended for inspecting the variable's value when it's set then just put a debugger statement and check it in the browser

Comment: but always console statement runs before function, so what to do in that case ?

Comment: Do you realise that you are declaring a callback that is not called and then expect to be able to access the value immediately, before the value is set? it's just plain javascript

Comment: yes, i know , that's why i put this as question and ask for alternate or correction

Comment: Just call `$scope.uploadedFile()` **before** your `console.log`, obviously, as @SamiTriki tried to tell you.