# How to synchronize two onloadend functions in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2/4 and I've reached a place that I can read multiple files from local directory. In my function, data (from each file) is parsed and pushed into 2 different arrays but after onloadend functions I can't access arrays data and I suppose this is a synchronization problem.

My Code:

```
changeListener($event: any) {
       this.readFile($event.target);
    }
readFile(input: any) {
  var self = this;
  var files : File [] = input.files;
  var employeeSet : Employee [] = new Array<Employee>();
  var serviceSet : Service [] = new Array<Service>();
  for (let i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
            console.log(files[i].name);

            if (files[i].name == 'employees') {
              var employeeReader : FileReader = new FileReader();
              employeeReader.readAsText(files[i]);

              employeeReader.onload = function(e) {
              var alldata = employeeReader.result;
              var allTextlines = alldata.split(/\r?\n/);

              for (var i=0; i < allTextlines.length; i++) {
                var columns = allTextlines[i].split('|');
                var employee : Employee = new Employee();
                if (columns[0] != '') {
                  employee.id = Number(columns[0]);
                  employee.firstName = columns[1];
                  employee.lastName = columns[2];
                  employee.jobPosition = columns[3];
                  employee.status = columns[4];
                  employee.company.name = columns[5];
                  employee.mobilePhone = columns[6];
                  employee.iternalNumber = columns[7];
                  employee.email = columns[8];
                  employee.hireDate = columns[9];
                  var totalServices = columns[10].split(',');
                  for (var j = 0; j < totalServices.length; j++) {
                    var serviceDescr = totalServices[j];
                    employee.services.push(serviceDescr);
                  }

                  employeeSet.push(employee);



                }
                // self.apiServ.addUser(user).subscribe(
                //   (data) => {
                //     if( data instanceof Observable) {
                //       data.subscribe(
                //         (f) => {console.log(f);
                //         });
                //     }
                //   }
                // );
              }
              console.log(employeeSet);
              self.complete.next(employeeSet);
              // console.log('Tha steiloume ston server to akoloutho array: \n', resultSet);
            };
          } else if(files[i].name == 'services') {

            var serviceReader : FileReader =  new FileReader();
            serviceReader.readAsText(files[i]);

            serviceReader.onload = function(e) {
            var alldata = serviceReader.result;
            var allTextlines = alldata.split(/\r?\n/);
            for (var i=0; i < allTextlines.length; i++) {
              var columns = allTextlines[i].split('|');
              var service : Service = new Service();
              if (columns[0] != '') {
                service.id = Number(columns[0]);
                service.description = columns[1];
                service.price = columns[2];
                service.cost = columns[3];

                serviceSet.push(service);


              }
            }
            console.log(serviceSet);
            self.complete.next(serviceSet);
          };



  }




}



// Here I want to access the data but i cant. 




}
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move employeeSet outside of methods to make it global in your controller.

Comment: why dont you look at `forkJoin`

Comment: @ice13 I moved it outside my method as public array, but even now when I console.log(employeeSet) after onloadend, it shows this : [] on console, filled with data but still not accessible.

Comment: Well, you need to use it after you set it. If you use it on onloaded event of component, it would be empty indeed. Not sure what use case you want, when you want to use it or how.

Answer (score 2):

I achieve something similar working with Promises (it remains being async but in a better way to handle it). You should be able to work with your arrays inside the then method.

ImageHelper.ts

```
export class ImageInfo {

  name: string;
  size: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;

}

export class ImageHelper {

  static getImageInfo(image: File): Promise<ImageInfo> {

    const imageInfo: ImageInfo = new ImageInfo();

    return new Promise<ImageInfo>((resolve, reject) => {

      try {

        imageInfo.name = image.name;
        imageInfo.size = image.size;

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = (onLoadEvent) => {

          const imageAux = new Image();
          imageAux.src = reader.result;

          imageAux.onload = function () {

            imageInfo.width = imageAux.width;
            imageInfo.height = imageAux.height;

            resolve(imageInfo);
          };
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
      } catch (error) {

        reject(error);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

And wherever.

```
principalUpload(event) {

  ImageHelper.getImageInfo(event.target.files[0])
    .then((imageInfo: ImageInfo) => console.log(imageInfo));
  ...
}
```

I hope this help someone more.